# how do you do battle mode in skylanders swap force?

Tags: skylanders-swap-force

How do you do battle mode in *Skylanders Swap Force*? I go to the main menu and it says story mode.

Answer (score 1):

Right under Story Mode, you'll find an option for Arena Modes. Select that, select a Save Game slot, and then select Battle Arena.